# How to update X and Y coordinate when hovering an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, hover

I have an image that changes position when I click inside a div like this:

```
mainDiv.click(function (e) {

    var mouseX = e.clientX,
        mouseY = e.clientY;

        test2 = Math.atan(mouseY/mouseX);
        test3 = ((test2 * 180) / 3.14);

        $("#hgun").rotate(test3);  
});
```

But it only changes position when I click inside the div. How can I make it change position when I hover inside the div ?

Comment: Look at all [JQuery mouse events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .hover() method binds handlers for both mouseenter and mouseleave events. You can use it to simply apply behavior to an element during the time the mouse is within the element.

**It is called like this:**

```
$(selector).hover(handlerIn, handlerOut)
```

**Which is short for:**

```
$(selector).mouseenter(handlerIn).mouseleave(handlerOut);
```

**In your case that would be:**

```
    mainDiv.hover(function (e) {
        var mouseX = e.clientX,
            mouseY = e.clientY;

        test2 = Math.atan(mouseY / mouseX);
        test3 = ((test2 * 180) / 3.14);
        $("#hgun").rotate(test3);
    },
function (e) {
    //On mouseleave
});
```

***Further read***: [jQuery hover documentation](http://api.jquery.com/hover/), [jQuery mouse events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/)

---

**Update**, based on author's comment:

I am not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve, but if you want your calculation and the related actions to be made every time the mouse moves within the container, you can use the [mousemove](http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/) event.

I've done a simple Fiddle based on your code, **check it out**: http://jsfiddle.net/sQ4Z4/1/

I used the first [jQuery Rotate Plugin](https://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/) I found, which might not be the one you used, but it should be enough to get you in the right direction.

**Basically your code should look something like this:**

```
mainDiv.mousemove(function (e) {
    var mouseX = e.clientX,
        mouseY = e.clientY;

    test2 = Math.atan(mouseY / mouseX);
    test3 = ((test2 * 180) / 3.14);
    $("#hgun").rotate(test3);
});
```

Comment: The problem I have now is that as soon as I enter the box with the mouse, it rotates there, but when I'm inside the box it does not rotate. The x and y need to be updated at all time?

Comment: Check my answer again, I've added a demo and some additional information and references.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

`mainDiv.click(function (e) {`

to

`mainDiv.hover(function (e) {`

`hover` accepts two functions: The first is executed on `mouseenter`, the second on `mouseleave`.